# SQL の fetchAll() に指定する 'assoc' の意味は？

Tags: cakephp

SQL文を直接実行する場合、クックブックを見ると下記のように記載されていますが、
この'assoc'の意味を教えてください。

```
$sql = 'select * from Users';
$results = $connection->execute($sql)->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Answer (score 2):

マニュアルに記述がありました。
PDO のそれと同じように、'assoc' を指定すると返却される
結果セットから列名で値を取得できるようになるようです。

[CakePHP マニュアル](https://api.cakephp.org/4.0/class-Cake.Database.Statement.PDOStatement.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
PDOとか初心者で全然わからないですけど、
マニュアル上、適当な文字列を設定していたわけではなかったのですね。